# Jmeter remove brackets from results with regex

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have tis jdcb call results

**[{string_agg=1268#jm_eo_2283,1343#jm_eo_2333}]**

so i use this regex code  to remove brackets  (?<=[=]).*\d
In theory i should get only

**jm_eo_2283,1343#jm_eo_2333**

i have 2022-08-30 13:35:49,291 ERROR o.a.j.e.RegexExtractor: Error in pattern: '(?<=[=]).*\d'

Any idea what is going on?? Is a way to get the result without brackets??
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JDBC Request sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request):

> If the Variable Names list is provided, then for each row returned by a Select statement, the variables are set up with the value of the corresponding column (if a variable name is provided), and the count of rows is also set up. For example, if the Select statement returns 2 rows of 3 columns, and the variable list is A,,C, then the following variables will be set up:
>
> ```
> A_#=2 (number of rows)
> A_1=column 1, row 1
> A_2=column 1, row 2
> C_#=2 (number of rows)
> C_1=column 3, row 1
> C_2=column 3, row 2
> ```

So you should be able to access:

- first row as `${eo_id_1}`
- second row as `${eo_id_2}`
- etc.

More information: [Using JDBC Sampler in JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
=[0-9]*#(.*[0-9])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GsQhZk/1). Keep the template field set to `$1$`, it will extract the value *captured* with the first parenthesized pattern part.

*Details*:

- `=` - a `=` sign
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `#` - a `#` char
- `(.*[0-9])` - Group 1 (`$1$`): any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then a digit.